# Does method [load] need to call [super load]

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, method-swizzling

I know that many methods need to call its super class method and some methods dont need,

I'm looking about sth about method swizzling.It's initialized in the load method,and in the tutorial there is no `[super load]`.

i'm wondering if it's wrong or there is just no need to call `[super load]`.

```
+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];

        // When swizzling a class method, use the following:
        // Class class = object_getClass((id)self);

        SEL originalSelector = @selector(pushViewController:animated:);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(flbs_pushViewController:animated:);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod =
        class_addMethod(class,
                        originalSelector,
                        method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                        method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class,
                                swizzledSelector,
                                method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                                method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    });
}

#pragma mark - Method Swizzling

- (void)flbs_pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self flbs_pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
    });
    NSLog(@"flbs_pushViewController");
}
```

By the way,this method is used to fix the navigation corruption.

I happened to reappear the problem sometimes,and i debuggered it,i think it's about the thread.So i make this swizzling to add sth in the system method.

If you can tell sth about the navigation corruption problem or this method swizzling,i also very appreciate that.

Comment: Best practice to call [super load] so all components get communication of event taking place.

Comment: @nikhil84 Following any principle blindly is a great way to get yourself in a world of trouble. [Anyway,`+load` is a very special case.](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [`NSObject` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/load)
(emphasis added):

> A class’s `+load` method is called **after** all of its superclasses’ `+load` methods.

Which means that you don't have to call `[super load]` from your code.
The `load` method from all superclasses has already been called
by the Objective-C runtime *before* the method in your subclass is called.

Comment: ...So, if you call `[super load];`, the superclass' implementation will run _twice_!

Comment: but if i overwrite the [load] method?

Comment: @HensonFang: Sorry, I do not get what you are asking. This Q&A is about overloading the `load` method.